# Existence of a holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$ whose rank at (0,0) is 0 but at all other points is 2? ($f$ could also be defined on a domain in $\mathbb C^2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [Hartogs' extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_extension_theorem) to $|Df|^{-1}$, the reciprocal of the [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $f$.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand your argument. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @user135988 The determinant $|Df|$ is non-zero on $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and therefore $|Df|^{-1}$ is well-defined and holomorphic there.  The set $\{(0,0)\}$ has co-dimension two.  So...